# Why are article sometimes omitted with words such as "legendary" and "British"?

Tags: articles, zero-article

I noticed that the definite article is sometimes omitted with the word "legendary":

> A collaboration between **legendary** game designer Richard Garfield and
> Valve, Artifact offers the deepest gameplay and the highest-fidelity
> experience ever seen in a trading card game. ([Steam store](https://store.steampowered.com/app/583950/Artifact/))
>
> The Bellezza Nera and its sister model, the all white Bellezza Blanco,
> are the result of a particularly unusual **collaboration between**
> **legendary British guitarist** Eric Clapton and Japanese trendsetter
> Hiroshi Fujiwara.
> (Robert Shaw. Hand Made, Hand Played: The Art & Craft of Contemporary Guitars.)

Furthermore, as user user150719 correctly indicated in a comment to [the following question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/233114/article-use-in-collaboration-between-the-legendary) the indefinite article is sometimes dropped before nationalities, e.g. the seconds example above or:

> The story would open in 1969, when Cobham met **British** guitarist John McLaughlin in the seminal fusion band of Miles Davis ([The Mercury News](https://www.mercurynews.com/2008/04/02/for-drummer-cobham-bandleader-was-surprise-role/))

Google agrees with this article-less use showing over 100 results for "met British guitarist" but only 4 for "met a British guitarist."

I'd like to know why these omissions take place. Is there any grammar rule that covers these cases?

Comment: For the record, I asked [a similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/233114) on ELL but this one has a broader scope and thus—hopefully—may be more fitting here on ELU.

Comment: Nothing to do with "legendary" or "British".  You can equally say "...between game designer..." and "...between guitarist..."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not quite sure at this point. Are you suggesting that "legendary game designer" and "legendary British guitarist" are "[false titles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_title)" and thus don't need an article?

Comment: 'False titles' is one of the many fancy names given to this type of construction, as the structure mimics say '[said] Professor John Smith' ('[said] opener Geoff Girlcott'). However, 'anarthrous nominal premodifier' is a term better explaining the grammar involved. And they're obviously what this question is all about.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perfect, thanks for the help, it all makes sense now. I'm marking this question as duplicate.

Comment: As often, Pullum has the sane advice: grammatical beyond question, totally acceptable in newspapers etc, but smells a bit off in novels.